# Android fragment on back transition

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I got a few fragments and I tried to sort out the transitions between them. I can go from **Main -> A -> B -> C**. Then once I am done with the stuffs in **C**, I wanted to go back to **B -> A -> Main**. This is the desired transition I wanted to achieve.

However, with my current code, there is something weird with the transition. I go from **Main -> A -> B -> C**, then inside **C** I am doing some SQL to create data in database, once I am done, I go back to **B**. However, from there, when I pressed back button, it go back to **C -> B -> A -> Main**. There is an unnecessary **C** in the back transition.

Inside my **Main**, I am calling **A** like this:

```
final SettingActivity settingFragment = new SettingActivity();
ft.replace(R.id.frame,settingFragment);
ft.addToBackStack("tag");
ft.commit();
```

Inside my **A**, I am calling **B** like this:

```
FragmentTransaction it = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
it.replace(R.id.frame,categoryFragment);
it.addToBackStack("tag");
it.commit();
```

Inside my **B**, I am calling **C** like this:

```
FragmentTransaction et = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
et.replace(R.id.frame,editFragment);
et.addToBackStack("tag");
et.commit();
```

Then inside my **C**, when I am successfully inserted a record in database, I am calling **B** like this:

```
// button on click listener
new GetAllCategoriesAsyncTask(
            new GetAllCategoriesAsyncTask.OnRoutineFinished() {
                public void onFinish() {

                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    FragmentTransaction it = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                    bundle.putSerializable("categorylist", GetAllCategoriesAsyncTask.categoryList);
                    categoryFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    it.replace(R.id.frame,categoryFragment);
                    it.addToBackStack("tag");
                    it.commit();
                }
            }).execute();
```

Then inside my **B**, I am getting the data like this in onCreate():

```
categoryList = (ArrayList<Category>) getArguments().getSerializable("categorylist");
```

Comment: why are u replacing fragment B from C. it is already in stack so when you back press B become visible

Comment: So I should use .add() instead or .replace()? I thought the replace is something like when you switch intent which you need to specify where it goes to

Comment: nothing. just backpress

Comment: Oh because after I create the record, I am pulling data from database as well and I need to to pass it back to the previous fragment

Comment: then in onresume of B fetch data and show it

Answer (score 1):

On button click pop the current fragment from stack which is **C** , instead of adding **B** again in the stack. So, replace the button onClick code with below line of code:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

`Bundle` is used when you transferring data to next screen. For transferring data to previous screen you need to use callbacks.

For reference please find below attached link :[Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: Sorry but I keep all the code same and add in the line above when button on click or?

Comment: hi @DeniseTan replace your onClick code with above line of code.

Comment: You mean replace the four lines with the pop()? But then when my button onclick, I am pulling data from database and I wanted to pass it back to the B. As in I am getting the data from AsyncTask and pass back by Bundle. So I need to specify where it goes to

Comment: @DeniseTan Correct!, replace your four lines with the above line. For passing the data to previous fragment you need to use callback.